# What is Class Libaray(iOS) in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Why there is a Class Library in Xamarin in iOS section "Class Library(iOS)" and what is difference between "Class Library(iOS)" and PCL Targeting Xamarin.iOS

Why we need this and what are the pros and cons

Comment: Essentially, there is no difference between an iOS class library and a PCL that targets only iOS except the latter gives you the option to add more platforms to target.

Answer (score 4):

A Class Library is a project that creates a DLL file targeting a specific platform.  An iOS Class Library creates a DLL for consumption by Xamarin.iOS projects only.

A Portable Class Library (PCL) is a library that can target multiple platforms, including Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android, as well as Windows Phone and other .NET platforms.

If you want to share code between multiple platforms, you would use a PCL.  If you are only interested in a single platform, use a platform specific class library.

Comment: To add to Jason's answer: An iOS Class Library can also use UIKit and other iOS frameworks while a PCL library cannot.